# CRUD operations in angularjs with REST API

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, rest, crud

The CRUD operations with AngularJS are working fine. On click of submit button values get submitted in db, but its not getting reflected on view with at the same time. 
Either I required separate button for showing values from database or I need to click twice.

My view:

```
<div style="float:left; margin-left:50px;">
    <div><label for="id">Update Records</label></div><br>
<table>
<tr >
    <td><label for="id">Id:</label> </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id" ng-model="user.id"/></td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td><br><label for="uname">Name:</label> </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="uname" ng-model="user.uname"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><br><label for="ucity">City:</label> </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ucity" ng-model="user.ucity"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
    <a ng-click="updatecust(user.id,user.uname,user.ucity)" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
    </td>
</tr> 
<!--<tr>
    <td><br>
        <a ng-click="viewtable()" class="btn btn-primary">View All</a>
        </td>
</tr> -->
</table>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
   var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', ['templateservicemod', 'navigationservice','restservice']);

  $scope.updatecust=function(id,name,city){
          console.log("update is clicked");
          $scope.user={id:id,uname:name,ucity:city};
          RestService.update(id,name,city).success( RestService.vieww().success(viewdata));
      };
```

REST API:

```
var restservice = angular.module('restservice', [])

.factory('RestService', function ($http) {

return{

        update: function(id,name,city){
            console.log(id+name+city);
            return $http.get("http://localhost/code/index.php/demo/updatedemo?id="+id+"&   uname="+name+"&ucity="+city,{});
        }
}

});
```

Comment: are you getting data in viewdata?

Comment: yes.i'm able to get data in viewdata.
 RestService.update(id,name,city).success( RestService.vieww().success(viewdata)); is this statement is ok??

Comment: That makes no sense at first look, you aren't doing anything outside AngularJS but it looks like the `$digest` process doesn't run on Rest action, try `$scope.$digest()` after assigning http response to scope just for sake of confirming it

Comment: @user,doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

```
RestService.update(id,name,city).success( RestService.vieww().success(viewdata));
```

this should be changed to

```
RestService.update(id,name,city).success(function(){
    RestService.vieww().success(function(data){
        $scope.viewdata = data.data;
    }));
});
```

by considering that, you have RestService function vieww to get the data array.

and in your HTML, you need to do ngRepeat for viewdata to display the table.